# digital ocean ubuntu 14.04 hosting multiple node JS apps

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, hosting, appdomain, digital-ocean

I am a beginner at node JS and web hosting in general. After playing around with the server, I have a node JS app running at my domain and it is using the port 3000. Is there a way of running multiple node JS apps in my ubuntu server 14.04 like this:

mydomain.com/nodejsapp1

mydomain.com/nodejsapp2

Right now I am only running a single app on the domain. This was done by using nginx. Is there any way I could run multiple node JS apps in a single domain like the example I gave above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, run those application the same way you run the first one, but specify other ports for them (i.e. 3001, 3002, etc.). Configure your nginx accordingly (same configuration like for the first application, but point it to your other applications on ports 3001, 3002, etc.).

And, I found this documentation on Digital Ocean website, describing exactly what you want to do: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04 the way I suggested. Just follow the steps from their tutorial.